# jQuery to serialize selected option's value, not label

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a select control:

```
<select name="AdditionalCategory">
  <option value="1">Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

I then use jQuery to send AJAX request, serializing the form:

```
$.post("../../d/up.php",$("#main").serialize(),
          function(data){
```

But, if I choose Category 1 for example, the serialize() function serializes the label, not the value of the option. So the request would be `up.php/?AdditionalCategory=Category 1`

Is there a way to tell the function to send the value, like this:
`up.php/?AdditionalCategory=1`

Comment: What is `#main` here? Please provide more HTML here...

Comment: @void probably the form id

Comment: Yes it is the formId, it's rather big form, but I don't think that there is an error in coding. The scripts works fine, except it is not serializing what I want it to in the case of the select control.

Comment: there is a missing closing </option> tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine but there is a slight error in your HTML form which is the closing tag of `<option>` you have is `</value>` which shoule be `</option>` instead.

Check working code below:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#but").click(function() {
    console.log($("#main").serialize());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main">
  <select name="AdditionalCategory">
  <option value="1" selected>Category 1</option>
  <option value="2">Category 2</option>
</select>
</form>

<button id="but">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake writing the question. The original html is fine.
I don't understand how can your code work... Can it be a difference in versions?

Comment: No it should not.. Just check once if you do not have one more select with name `AdditionalCategory ` inside the form container..

Comment: you're right. It is not the syntax error that you pointed out, but it was a syntax error after all... Thanks